# writing a custom function inside d3.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to add all the numbers from a tag. I am using `d3.json` to reference the file. I am mixing some jQuery in it and I think it is not going very well.

How should I do this?

Once I get the sum I will do some mathematical operations on it to reduce the value of `consumption_gj_` so that I can pass it as a radius to the circle like this.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
var sum = 0;
//adding values
    function radiusData(d){
        +sum = d.consumption_gj_;
        alert(sum)
    }
     //here I am trying to append the total to a div
     $('.test').append(sum);
```

Right now I am just doing this `d.consumption_gj_ / 10000` to come up with a reasonable number but its not really working out.

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/Vn7mf/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop to iterate over the values and add them to the sum:

```
data.forEach(function(d) { sum += +d.consumption_gj_; });
```

Modified jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn7mf/10/).